# JSON for Java, Encode a JSON array - Streaming

Tags: java, json

[I have some code to create a JSON array. In this code I am passing some values to `x`, `y`, `z` in a loop which looks like this.

```
   JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
   String jsonText = null;
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
       list.add(new Integer(x));
       list.add(new Integer(y));
       list.add(new Integer(z));
       jsonText = list.toString();
  }
  System.out.print(jsonText);
```

This gives output as

```
[1234,245,10,312,234,122,1234,67788,345,235,001,332]
```

How can I get these values in a single array like this?

```
[[1234,245,10],[312,234,122],[1234,67788,345],[235,001,332]]
```

] I got the answer for this question needs answer for the below question.

I used one of the below solutions.
Thanks for the response from you guys.

Now i got JSON formate nested Arrays which looks like this

```
[
[[1234,245,10],[312,234,122],[1234,67788,345],[235,001,332]],
[[1234,245,10],[312,234,122],[1234,67788,345],[235,001,332],[1234,67788,3450]],
[[1234,245,10],[312,234,122],[1234,67788,345],[235,001,332],[1234,67788,34534]]]
```

SO i have One big Array which contains three arrays(this can be 2 or more than three arrays sometimes) and each of these three array contains some arrays, in this above example

what is the reverse procedure ? i mean what if i want those values from these arrays. In the same way how i have did. using JSON
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
list.get()  this get method will give me what i requies ?
I used the org.json Java API.

Thanks friends for helping me till now.

Comment: Is that last line (the example output) right?

Comment: Sorry, the output is something like this  [1234,245,10,312,234,122,1234,67788,345,235,001,332]  Can u please tell how to get the above output liek this [1234,245,10][312,234,122][1234,67788,345][235,001,332]

Comment: Are you sure that's the output you want? Based on original question, I would have expected the desired output to be `[[1234,245,10],[312,234,122],[1234,67788,345],[235,001,332]]` (i.e. an array of nested arrays) rather than `[1234,245,10][312,234,122][1234,67788,345][235,001,332]` (i.e a string that looks like arrays without any separation). The second doesn't actually make sense, since it is not proper JSON unless you wrap it in `"` quotes, and then it would be a string, not a series of arrays parsable by JSON.

Comment: Yes you are right @Chadwick it should be something like this. [[1234,245,10],[312,234,122],[1234,67788,345],[235,001,332]], it should be an array instead of string, thanks for pointing me my mistake

Comment: Glad you got an answer that worked for you, but don't edit a question just to add another. Create a new question (or search to see if it's been asked already) - it's ok if it's the reverse of this one, as long as you don't ask the same question! You can even refer to this question explicitly to show some background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you want is a syntactically correct JSON array of nested arrays of integers (original post requests invalid JSON). If not, go with [@BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700107/json-for-java-encode-a-json-array-streaming/3700250#3700250).

To get an array containing sub-arrays, simply create the sub-arrays as `int[]` arrays, and add them directly to your main `JSONArray`.

```
public int[] getThreeValues() { // example
    Random r = new Random();
    return new int[] { r.nextInt(100), r.nextInt(100), r.nextInt(100) };
}

public void execute() {

    JSONArray master = new JSONArray();

    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        master.put(getThreeValues());
    }

    System.out.println(master);
}
```

**Result:**

```
[[3,13,37],[24,4,64],[61,2,1],[97,13,86]]
```

Note: I'm not sure which JSON library your using, so I used the [org.json Java API](http://www.json.org/java/index.html), which uses `put(...)` rather than `add(...)`. Also, that particular library supports adding int[] arrays directly to JSONArray - yours may not, in which case you'd need to build the nested JSONArrays and add them to your master.

Answer (score 4):

Just put it in another `JSONArray`.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(list);
String jsonText = array.toString();
```

---

**Update**: as per your comment:

> Sorry, the output is something like this
>
> ```
> [1234,245,10,312,234,122,1234,67788,345,235,001,332]
> ```
>
> Can you please tell how to get the above output like this
>
> ```
> [1234,245,10][312,234,122][1234,67788,345][235,001,332]
> ```

Several ways:

1. Concatenate to the `jsonString`.

   ```
   String jsonText = ""; // Start with empty string.
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
       JSONArray list = new JSONArray(); // Create new on each iteration.
       list.add(new Integer(x));
       list.add(new Integer(y));
       list.add(new Integer(z));
       jsonText += list.toString(); // += concatenates to existing string.
   }
   System.out.print(jsonText);
   ```
2. Since String concatenating using `+=` in a loop is memory hogging and slow, rather use `StringBuilder`.

   ```
   StringBuilder jsonText = new StringBuilder();
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
       JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
       list.add(new Integer(x));
       list.add(new Integer(y));
       list.add(new Integer(z));
       jsonText.append(list.toString();
   }
   System.out.print(jsonText.toString());
   ```

Comment: i got both the answers. I have two different approaches one with concatenating arrays and one with nested arrays. So i got you solution and aslo @chadwick's Solution. Thanks for the responces you guys are genius. thanks for the help.

Comment: It's a matter of using human logical thinking powers. It's however sad that your initial question was completely wrong.

Comment: Yes i agree with you, But as i told i have to use for both the answers urs and @Chadwick's. Buts it my foult that i should have ask for both the aproches. Your answer helps me with String of names which am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put the list inside a JSONArray

e.g.

```
   JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
   String jsonText = null;
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
       list.add(new Integer(x));
       list.add(new Integer(y));
       list.add(new Integer(z));
  }

  JSONArray finalList = new JSONArray();
  finalList.put(0, list);
  jsonText = finaList.toString();
  System.out.print(jsonText);
```

Or (**not recommended at all**) hack your output,

e.g.

```
jsonText += "[" + jsonText + "]";
System.out.print(jsonText);
```